# How can I view top scored questions ever asked?

Tags: support, statistics

There is https://ux.stackexchange.com/?tab=month - but it covers just latest month.

Is it possible to see top questions ever asked? I just found this site and I think that I can learn something about this topic by looking what kind of questions were asked.

Maybe also top rated answers, though not sure how often it would be interesting to read highly rated answer for poorly rated question.

[How can I see the most popular questions of all times?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86735/how-can-i-see-the-most-popular-questions-of-all-times) is directing to part of interface missing from https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the 'Questions' menu on the left-hand side (or just go to https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions).

[image]

Then you can get some extra filter options from there. Such as to this page: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes